# will tf.dataset.cache work in distributed training when shuffle is enabled

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

It looks like tf.dataset.cache can help improve the data pipeline performance by caching the data in worker's memory. So in 2nd and following epochs, the data can be directly accessed from RAM instead of going through file system.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache

Question is in case of distributed training and when shuffle is enabled, each worker won't read the same data in next epoch, would cache still be beneficial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question is in case of distributed training and when shuffle is
> enabled, each worker won't read the same data in next epoch, would
> cache still be beneficial?

There is no beneficial, as you rightly mentioned if you call [`.cache()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache) on a dataset, it will produce exactly same data during each iteration.

To get randomized data then you can call `shuffle` after calling `cache`.

```
train_dataset = mnist_train.map(scale).cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
eval_dataset = mnist_test.map(scale).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

When doing distributed training, please refer [this article](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/#tfdata-performance-tips) for tf.data performance tips on `dataset.batch`,  `dataset.cache` and `dataset.prefetch`.

Comment: if I call shuffle after cache, what's the effect of cache then?

Comment: @Jaylin, as such there is no effect of cache. As mentioned in answer If you wish to randomize the iteration order, make sure to call shuffle after calling cache.